# catch exception thrown from deepest level call in upper method

Tags: java

Catch the exception on upper class is what I wonder. I have more than one method call layer. In the deepest level, exception is thrown. In the top level how can I catch?

```
void foo() {
   bar(); <---- catch exception in here
}

void bar() {
   // .... <--- throws IOException or ExecutionException or InterruptedException
}

OR case two


void foo() {
   bar(); <---- catch exception in here
}

void bar() {
   gbr();
}

void gbr() {
      // .... <--- throws IOException or ExecutionException or InterruptedException
}
```

Comment: You can catch it normally, there's no trick.

Comment: @Kayaman I donot understand. Should I wrote all exception should be twrown to signature of method? Can you show example?

Answer (score 3):

### Exception handling

As described in the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/figures/essential/exceptions-errorOccurs.gif), an `Exception` is caught by the first exception handler (*try/catch* block) in the call stack that can handle the thrown exception type.

[image: Exception handling]

### Case 1

If you don't define an exception handler (a *try/catch* block) in `bar` you need to specify that the method *throws* some exceptions, which can be handled by `foo` (at the previous step of the call stack).

```
void foo() {
    try {
        bar();
    } catch (IOException io) {
        // Do something
    } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
        // Do something
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        // Do something
    }
}

void bar() throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    // .... <--- throws IOException or ExecutionException or InterruptedException
}
```

### Case 2

If you don't define an exception handler either in `gbr` or in `bar`, you have to specify that both methods *throw* exceptions, which can be handled in `foo`.

```
void foo() {
    try {
        bar();
    } catch (IOException io) {
        // Do something
    } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
        // Do something
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
        // Do something
    }
}

void bar() throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    gbr();
}

void gbr() throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    // .... <--- throws IOException or ExecutionException or InterruptedException
}
```

### General case

If you don't want to distinguish which exception was thrown you can use the class `Exception` which is an ancestor of all exceptions ([docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html)), thus matches all of them:

```
void foo() {
    try {
        bar();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Do something
    }
}

void bar() throws Exception {
    // .... <--- throws IOException or ExecutionException or InterruptedException
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A thrown exception will be caught by the first relevant try/catch block. If such a block doesn't exist, then the program will crash due to an unhandled exception.

Therefore, if gbr() throws an exception which isn't caught, it'll return to bar. If bar() doesn't catch it, then it'll return to foo(), etc until it'll return to main().